# No vibrate in flutter notifications

Tags: flutter, vibration

I am using firebase cloud functions to send a notification to a particular user. This is the payload that I am sending from the functions.

`var payload = {
    notification: {
        sound: "default",
        color: "#ff3296fa",
        vibrate: "300",
        priority: 'high',
        notificationType: "52",
        title: titleToBeShown,
        body: message['message'],
        icon: 'ic_launcher',
    },
    data: {
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
        channelId: channelID,
        channelName: channelName,
        channelType: channelType
    },
};`

I am using firebase_messaging (flutter package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging) to receive the notifications and I have written the codes for onMessage, onLaunch and onResume methods.

So when I send a message using Admin SDK `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)`, it sends it without vibration and sound. How can I add vibration and sound to it? Right now, it feels like a silent notification then. Which will easily be ignored by the users. Both in android and ios, its the same problem.

Comment: have u found an answer to your question? I face the same problem when sending notification only sound play no vibration.

Comment: @Daniel.V It's seems that vibration is disabled by default. Looking for the same problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69029951/fcm-flutter-enable-notification-vibration

Comment: @Daniel.V if you are looking for a fast solution for android notification only, you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications. As you can see it enables to create custom notification channels (android) including vibrations.

Answer (score 1):

The `sound` field does not go in the `notification` object. It belongs in the `android` and `apns` objects. Your payload should look like this:

```
var payload = {
  data: {
    channelId: channelID,
    channelName: channelName,
    channelType: channelType
  },
  android: {
    priority: 'high',
    notification: {
      title: titleToBeShown,
      body: message['message'],
      icon: 'ic_launcher',
      sound: 'default',
      color: '#ff3296fa',
      clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',

      // Not sure what this is supposed to be, but not a valid parameter
      notificationType: '52',
    },
  },
  apns: { ... }
};
```

I've filled in the Android fields, but I'm not familiar with APNS payloads. Check out the FCM documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#defining_the_message) for more details and you can see the available payload options for APNS [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html).

Comment: I tried this. But it gives me this error. Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid "android" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification".

Comment: Are you using the admin sdk to send the message?

Comment: Yes I am using admin sdk. I will update in the question too.