# FCM flutter enable notification vibration

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a Flutter application for Android and IOS. I have created notification channels for Android according to this [article](https://rechor.medium.com/creating-notification-channels-in-flutter-android-e81e26b33bec).

My node.js payload:

```
const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "title",
      },
      android: {
        priority: "high",
        ttl: 60 * 60 * 1,
        notification: {
          channel_id: 'YO',
        },
      },
      apns: {
        payload: {
          aps: {
            sound: "sound_03.caf"
          }
        },
        headers: {
          "apns-collapse-id": "yo",
          "apns-priority": "10"
        }
      },
      priority: 10
    }
```

My notifications are working just fine, for both Android and IOS using. The problem is that vibration is disabled by default.

**How to enable notification vibration for Android and IOS for Firebase Cloud Messaging?**

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `sound` property to `default` so it makes uses the default sound if sound is enabled and it vibrates if the device is on vibrate.

You can update your payload to this:

```js
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: "title",
    sound: "default"
  },
  android: {
    priority: "high",
    ttl: 60 * 60 * 1,
    notification: {
      channel_id: 'YO',
    },
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        sound: "default"
      }
    },
    headers: {
      "apns-collapse-id": "yo",
      "apns-priority": "10"
    }
  },
  priority: 10
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Victor Eronmosele. I have just checked some apps, that are using the default sound, on my phone, and some are in vibrate and some not. How do I ensure that the "default" sound vibes?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I only needed to add it to the `notification` portion of the message payload.

Below is how it looks in Typescript (but the message JSON is all that matters).

```js
let tokens = ...
let message = {
    message: {
        notification: {
            title: title,
            body: body,
            sound: 'default', // <----- All I needed
        },
        data: {
            ...
        },
    }
}

firebase.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, message)
```